# returning values from MySQL stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql

I have created one stored procedure and its functioning well, what I am wanting is right now there is only one SQL statement in the stored procedure which is returning the expected values, can I add multiple SQL statements which will be resulting multiple vlues. Please let me know.

Here is my stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE amazonall(IN client_ids INT(11))
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(total_inserted) into ti from log_amazon_import  where client_id = client_ids and date_format(created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and CURDATE();
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and also please let me know how can I access those return values, thanks in advance.

Comment: "query" the call "fetch" the result, as with every normal query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you want to return multiple records - just return the data set.

- Populate (temporary) tables and read them after.
- Just run SELECT statements (without INTO) and read data set in the application, I know that mysqli extension allows it (functions: [more_results](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.more-results.php), [next_result](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.next-result.php), ...).